# Email Error with ColdFusion 10 and Apache 2.4

Tags: java, apache, coldfusion

When we upgraded to Apache 2.4 our emails started throwing "com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host..." errors.
(Same code base and connections as before.) 
Instances not upgraded work fine. Build in CF web server works fine.

Has anyone seen this?

- Windows 7.
- ColdFusion 10. Upgrade 17. Development.
- Apache 2.4.17.
- Java 1.8.0_60   (upgraded at the same time as the 2.4 upgrade).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Repeating SOLUTION above.

We found that the issue was with Java 1.8.0_60. Our solution was:

1. In cf administrator go to Java and JVM
2. In JVM ARGUMENTS add -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
   (NOTE NOTE NOTE all args are seperated by a space - one space only)
3. Submit changes, this takes a moment.
4. STOP and start CF
5. Now you should be able to verify email connection